# iOS background fetch only working with debugger

Tags: ios, notifications, apple-push-notifications, push

I've been looking at this for a few days now and making no progress. I've developed a small test iOS (9.2.1) app that receives push notifications from the Azure Notification Hub. Everything appears to work fine, including the background notification push so long as the app is launched via xcode and is in debug mode.

Every notification I receive via the following callback just writes a file to the documents folder on the device. If I use xcode device explorer, I can see these files appearing

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

    makefile(random file name based on timestamp);
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.NewData);
}
```

I have also enabled the following modes in the UIBackgroundModes section of the plist file

- fetch
- remote-notification

The paypload that I send to the ANS server is:

```
"aps":{ "sound":"default", "content-available":1 }
```

Like I have mentioned above, so long as the app is running via xcode, I can press the home button, but it into the background and it will receive the push data fine. However, if I disconnect the USB cable it will stop receiving the background push events.

It's worth noting that the in-built OS notification does appear. Does anyone know what could be the problem here?

**EDIT**
If I launch the app via xcode, unplug the USB, send the notification - nothing happens. As soon as i reconnect to xcode it comes in and the code is run! Is this something to do with certifications (development / production)

Comment: Will, I am experiencing the exact same issue you described. Did you figure anything out?

Comment: Hi! sort of... I re-followed the guide (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-ios-apple-push-notification-apns-get-started/) my biggest mistake was using the incorrect certificate. For testing / development you NEED to use the Debug certificate (the one you upload to azure). Also make sure you've got your Tags registered correctly. For testing, I ended up using the built in Visual Studio tools for sending test notifications!

Comment: Thanks Will. My problem ended up being that Apple disables background fetch while phone is in Low Battery Mode.

Comment: i will also keep an eye out for this one as well! Thanks!

Comment: I just had this issue ... other devices running the same build from TestFlight were properly processing background notifications, so I simply rebooted my device and that seemed to solve it for me.

Answer (score 0):

The `content-available` key indicates iOS should treat this as a silent notification. Silent notifications are silent - they do not show an alert, badge, or play a sound.

A notification payload that contains both the `content-available` key *and* user-facing features like a sound or alert may be treated as either. The behavior is undefined - a notification should be silent or not, not both.

Silent notifications are handled by `application(didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler)`, not `application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:)`. It's possible that when your app does not seem to be getting the notification that iOS is calling this method.

In your case, you may also be getting throttled by iOS. If silent notifications are received too frequently, if you app uses too many resources handling them, etc. iOS will delay delivery of the notification. It will *not* delay them when launched from Xcode.

1. Your silent notification should not include a sound. Make that a separate notification, or try playing a sound in the background from inside your app.
2. Check the rate you are sending silent notifications to your app. At most send 2 an hour.
3. Verify that your silent notification handling code does not use excessive CPU, memory, or energy. Target using 15mb or less when handling the silent notification. Also make sure the fetchCompletionHandler block is called with 30 seconds of iOS calling `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler`